# Unable to remove files using expect script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I would like to remove all log files inside directory /var/log/$some_project/

I can remove them using shell command :

```
sudo rm /var/log/$some_project/*.log
```

But I have created expect script as shown below. Where I pass the PASS (my system password) and FILES (/var/log/$some_project/*.log) but it does not delete the files. It deleted only one file the first one.

I also tried instead of passing FILES/*.log, I just passed /var/log/$some_project and use the second script. But still, I am not able to remove all the log files.

I have also tried passing each file to expect script and remove still it does not work.

First Script

```
set timeout -1
set PASS [lindex $argv 0];
set FILES [lindex $argv 1];
spawn sudo rm $FILES
expect "Password:"
send $PASS\r
set timeout -1
exit 0
expect eof
```

Second Script

```
set timeout -1
set PASS [lindex $argv 0];
set FILES [lindex $argv 1];
spawn sudo rm $FILES/*.log
expect "Password:"
send $PASS\r
set timeout -1
exit 0
expect eof
```

Please, I would want to expect to understand the wildcard character and remove the files from the directory specified.

Comment: I am not able to understand, Please someone help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a wildcard expression to a script, the shell in which you run the script expands the wildcard before starting the script. So by the time Expect runs, `[lindex $argv 1]` really contains only the first one of the files you want to removed

Comment: Yes, you are right...Could you please help me how can I implement it with or without expect...I don't want to user to enter the password.

Comment: Thanks your solution works....Thanks, I understood your answer